# Why are numeric keystrokes appearing twice?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C#. Using the code below, whenever I press a number key on my keyboard, it will display twice in the textbox. When I press "1" on the keyboard it will display
"11", and when I press "2" it will display "22". Why is this?

```
private void Window_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{

    if(!isNumeric(e.Text))
    {
        string display = string.Empty;
        display += e.Text;

        displayNum(display);
    }
    else
    {
        String inputOperator = string.Empty;
        inputOperator += e.Text;

        if (inputOperator.Equals("+"))
        {
            ApplySign(sign.addition, "+");
        }

    }
}

private bool isNumeric(string str)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^0-9]");
    return reg.IsMatch(str);
}

private void window_keyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9)
    {
        int num = e.Key - Key.D0;
        outputText2.Text += num;
    }

}

private void BtnNum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button num = ((Button)sender);
    displayNum(num.Content.ToString());
}
private void displayNum(String n)
    {
        if (operator1 == 0 && double.Parse(n) == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            if (operator1 == 0)
            {
                outputText2.Clear();
            }
            outputText2.Text += n;

            operator1 = double.Parse(outputText2.Text);
            outputText2.Text = Convert.ToString(operator1);         
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you're just registering the event twice? Check the designer-generated code for references to `window_keyUp()`

Comment: Is this a WPF program?

Comment: @GrantWinney sorry..i forgot to show the displaynum() function..now edited..xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two events that are handeling the Keyboard events. Although not really sure what the `displayNum()` method is doing

I am assuming the `Window_TextInput` event is the event you wish to primarily handle the event.

Try adding

`e.Handled = true;`

In the `Window_TextInput` method. If that doesn't solve the problem can you post the `displayNum()` method?

**EDIT:**

After further review of the code and trying the same I do not see the relevance for the `window_keyUp` method as your `Window_TextInput` handles the input characters and has more applicable logic for handling the `TextInput` changes.

After I removed the `window_keyUp` event method the output appeared as expected (although commented out the `ApplySign()` method.

Comment: sorry..i forgot to post the displayNum() function..im really sorry..now edited already..:)

Comment: thanks..since i understand the cause of the problem now from your answer..i jst comment out the "outputText2.Text += num" in windw_KeyUp  and it will not display twice now..thanks alot..:)

Answer (score 2):

You've subscribed to two window-level text-related events - `TextInput` and `KeyUp` - and both of them end up appending input to the TextBox.

- `window_keyUp` appends numbers to the TextBox
- It looks like `Window_TextInput` is supposed to append non-numeric characters, but your RegEx is incorrect (`[^0-9]` matches anything that is *not* numeric, so `IsNumeric` returns True if the input is not a number)

The effect is that every numeric key press shows up twice.

Comment: i think i got the common mistake..display both from textinput and keyup..thanks i was able to solve the problem now..:)

Comment: yeh..the function name is not correct..it suppose to be isNotNumeric..xD